# Closing serial port results in program crash on mac

Tags: java, macos, serial-port

I have made a program in java that connects to an external AVR microcontroller via a serial port (RS232).

When I want to close the serial connection, the java program crashes and freezes. However, this happens only on mac (OSX 10.9.3), and there is no problem on Windows.

I close the port in the following way:

```
private SerialPort serialPort;

public void closePort() {
serialPort.close();
}
```

I have tried the following code for fixing it: then there is no crash after closing port, but next time I want to open the same port, I get the port in use exception.

```
public class CloseThread extends Thread {

    private SerialPort port;

    public CloseThread(SerialPort port) {
        super();
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            port.getOutputStream().close();
            port.getInputStream().close();

            port.removeEventListener();
            port.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CloseThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the method I mentioned at the beginning:

```
public void closePort() throws Exception {
    new CloseThread(serialPort).start();
}
```

I would be extremely thankful if someone helped me solve this problem i.e. get the close port method not to cause a crash on a mac.

:))

Comment: Does the program crash? If so could you give us the stack trace. Does the computer crash? Try updating/reinstalling java.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `if`:

```
if(serialPort.isOpened())
    serialPort.closePort(); //Close serial port
```